# Pass SelectedValue in DropDownList from View Razor to Controller using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

when adding a customer (client) , I have a DropDownList of Number  , when I select RaisonSocial should get the value relative to the number : 
the Number and RaisonSocial are two attributes in the same table

This is my controller'action :

```
  [HttpGet]
public ActionResult Register()
    {
        ViewBag.No_ = new SelectList(dbCustomer.AURES_GROS_Customer.ToList(), "No_", "No_");

        ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser();
        // Get Raison Sociale relative to No_ selected 
       user.RaisonSociale = context.Users.First(c => c.No_.Equals(NumClient)).RaisonSociale;
        ViewBag.Remise = user.RaisonSociale;
        //ViewBag.Remise= new SelectList(dbCustomer.AURES_GROS_Customer.ToList(), "Name", "Name");


        return View();
    }
```

This is my View : // Register :

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal form-label-left", role = "form", @id = "demo-form2" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                    @*" Label de Numéro de Client"*@    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="No_" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">N° Client</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">

                            @Html.DropDownList("No_", (SelectList)ViewBag.No_, " -- Selectionner numéro de Client -- ", new { @id="test", onchange = "document.getElementById('NumClient').value = this.value;" })




                        </div>
                    </div>

                    @*" Label de Raison Sociale"*@
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="RaisonSociale">
                            Raison Sociale
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <input type="text" name="RaisonSociale" value="@ViewBag.Remise" readonly="readonly" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: To what GET method (the only one you have shown does not have any parameters).

Comment: You have reason , I modified my get method and add a parametres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your dropdown onchange function

```
@Html.DropDownList("No_", (SelectList)ViewBag.No_, " -- Selectionner numéro de Client -- ", new { @id="test", onchange = "getddlVal(this.value)" })
```

Javascript

```
function getddlVal(selectedval)
{
        window.location = '/Controller/action?ddlvalue=' + selectedval;

}
```

Comment: I modify my dropdown onchange function , and I add to registeraction a parametre named string ddlvalue , but it doesen't work

Comment: I get this Url : /Account/Register?ddlvalue=[object%20HTMLSelectElement]

Comment: modify change function in dropdown to this.value

Comment: i have modified the solution

Comment: Thanks a lot , It works finally , Thaks very much REDEVI_

Comment: Yes I forgot , I am a beginner in StackOverFlow ,